# Unity: How do I ensure that my objects are instantiated before they are accessed by the inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here's what I'm dealing with. I have a `Tile` class, a `TileController`, and a `TileControllerEditor`.

```
public class Tile
{
    public enum TileType {
        Blank, Portal
    }

    public TileType type;
}
```

---

```
public class TileController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The View component of a Tile
    public GameObject tileObject;
    // The Model component of a Tile
    public Tile tile;

    public Tile.TileType tileType {
        get {
            return tile.type;
        }
        set {
            tile.type = value;
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        tile = new Tile();
    }
}
```

---

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(TileController))]
public class TileControllerEditor : Editor
{
    TileController tc;
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        tc = (TileController)target;
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        // Provide a dropdown for tileType
        tc.tileType = (Tile.TileType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Tile Type", tc.tile.type);
    }
}
```

I want to make the `tileType` attribute of the `TileController` class available in the inspector as a dropdown. The issue I'm having is that in my custom inspector, when the `tileType` attribute is first accessed, `Awake()` has not been called yet, so `tile` is `null` and I get a `NullReferenceException`.

How do I make sure that my class members are fully instantiated before they are accessed by the inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize the `Tile` object at declaration, avoiding `Awake` altogether.

```
public class TileController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tileObject;
    public Tile tile = new Tile();

    public Tile.TileType tileType {
        get {
            return tile.type;
        }
        set {
            tile.type = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hah. Cool. I had no idea you could do that in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that works for me. Because I created the `TileController`s in another editor script, I was able to simply add an `Init()` method to `TileController` that functions as a constructor, which I call manually every time I create one.

```
public class TileController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The View component of a Tile
    public GameObject tileObject;
    // The Model component of a Tile
    public Tile tile;

    public Tile.TileType tileType {
        get {
            return tile.type;
        }
        set {
            tile.type = value;
        }
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        tile = new Tile();
    }
}
```

And then when I create the `TileController` (They are attached to a prefab, which I instantiate and call `GetComponent<TileController>()` on):

```
void GenerateTiles()
{
    ...
    GameObject tileObject = Instantiate(boardController.tilePrefab);
    TileController tileController = tileObject.GetComponent<TileController>();
    tileController.Init();
    ...
}
```